# install 32bit Java JDK on CentOS 6.5 32bit

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, centos6

I am trying to `wget` to install 32bit JDK on 32bit CentOS 6.5. CentOS is running on a vmware player VM inside Windows. Next step is to set the System Environment Variables. I am building a small Hadoop cluster on CentOS VMs for testing purposes.

When I type `wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u25-b06/jdk-6u25-linux-i586-rpm.bin`
into my CentOS 6.5 Terminal, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: certificate common name “www.oracle.com” doesn’t match requested host name “edelivery.oracle.com”.
To connect to edelivery.oracle.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

How do I install JDK via CentOS Terminal?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need Java6?  If you get the latest version, it should be available without needing to sign up for an Oracle account.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle requires authentication to download archived versions of Java 6 at this time, you cannot download them directly with wget as a result. Please use a web browser to download the package.

Comment: I am seeing the same when I try and get a v7 installer.